# Solve polynomial for y

Tags: python, lambda, equation

I'm taking in a function (e.g. y = x**2) and need to solve for x. I know I can painstakingly solve this manually, but I'm trying to find instead a method to use. I've browsed numpy, scipy and sympy, but can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Currently I'm making a lambda out of the function so it'd be nice if I'm able to keep that format for the the method, but not necessary.

Comment: @S.Lott: I presume he intends to solve this for arbitrary polynomials.

Comment: @S.Lott: That's clearly just an example. (note the "e.g.")

Comment: @S.Lott, I'm sorry for the confusion. "solve for y" was a typo, I meant solve for x, as you assumed in your first comment. and yes, i am looking to solve arbitrary polynomials. thanks though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking for numerical solutions (i.e. just interested in the numbers, not the symbolic closed form solutions), then there are a few options for you in the [SciPy.optimize](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.optimize.html) module. For something simple, the [`newton`](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.optimize.minpack.html#newton) is a pretty good start for simple polynomials, but you can take it from there.

For symbolic solutions (which is to say to get y = x**2 -> x = +/- sqrt(y)) [SymPy](http://sympy.org) [solver](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html) gives you roughly what you need. The whole SymPy package is directed at doing symbolic manipulation.

Here is an example using the *Python* interpreter to solve the equation that is mentioned in the question. You will need to make sure that SymPy package is installed, then:

```
>>>> from sympy import * # we are importing everything for ease of use
>>>> x = Symbol("x")
>>>> y = Symbol("y")     # create the two variables
>>>> equation = Eq(x ** 2, y) # create the equation
>>>> solve(equation, x)
[y**(1/2), -y**(1/2)]
```

As you see the basics are fairly workable, even as an interactive algebra system. Not nearly as nice as [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), but then again, it is free and you can incorporate it into your own programs. Make sure to read the [*Gotchas and Pitfalls*](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/gotchas.html) section of the SymPy documentation on how to encode the appropriate equations.

If all this was to get a quick and dirty solutions to equations then there is always [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x**2+%3D+y+for+x).

Comment: thanks, but I would like the function to be returned ( e.g. INPUT: y = x**2 OUTPUT: sqrt(y) or x = sqrt(y) )

Comment: @Nona see my updated answer about SymPy. @kindall also gave you the answer.

Comment: cool, i see it now, `pde.pde_separate`. i dont follow the argument's it requires though, separate(eq,fun,sep), what's the partial differential equation? fun i assume would be my lambda, sep is just a placeholder for the results? strategy looks like i would actually use 'add'. I'm trying to follow the example, but I think I'm getting lost with `u, X, T = map(Function, 'uXT')` .... Thanks again!!

Comment: @Nona since the equation that you mentioned in your question is not a partial differential equation, I wouldn't worry about the pde module. I updated my answer with simple intro. You should read the SymPy documentation, they have a pretty good tutorial.

Comment: You should be aware that for polynomials of degree 5 or more, there may not be a solution involving just arithmetic and powers.

Answer (score 4):

Use Newton-Raphson via [scipy.optimize.newton](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html). It finds roots of an equation, i.e., values of *x* for which f(*x*) = 0. In the example, you can cast the problem as looking for a root of the function f(*x*) = *x*² - *y*. If you supply a lambda that computes *y*, you can provide a general solution thus:

```
def inverse(f, f_prime=None):
    def solve(y):
        return newton(lambda x: f(x) - y, 1, f_prime, (), 1E-10, 1E6)
    return solve
```

Using this function is quite simple:

```
>>> sqrt = inverse(lambda x: x**2)
>>> sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951
```

Depending on the input function, you may need to tune the parameters to `newton()`. The current version uses a starting guess of 1, a tolerance of 10<sup>-10</sup> and a maximum iteration count of 10<sup>6</sup>.

For an additional speed-up, you can supply the derivative of the function in question:

```
>>> sqrt = inverse(lambda x: x**2, lambda x: 2*x)
```

In fact, without it, the function actually uses the secant method instead of Newton-Raphson, which relies on knowing the derivative.

Comment: can you explain how this would be used? I've read it through but don't quite follow.

Answer (score 3):

Check out SymPy, specifically the [solver](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! I'm waiting to pick an answer (though you've got my upvote) because this still isn't quite clear to me. Maybe you could check out my comment on martineno and see if you could help clarify? really appreciated.